# Causing an event in Python when any error happens ever?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, spyder

I'm not sure exactly how to ask what I'm asking, and I don't know if any sample code would really be relevant here, so if clarification is necessary just ask.

I have a non-trivial program in Python that does a couple of things. It reads from some SQL Server database tables, executes some DDL in SQL Server (both of these with pyodbc), analyzes some data, and has a GUI to orchestrate everything so users in the future besides me can automate the process.

Everything is functioning as it should, but obviously I don't expect future users to always play by the rules. I can explicitly indicate what input is wrong (i.e. fields left empty), but there are quite a bit of things that can go wrong. Try-catch structures are out of the question because they cause a few issues in the web of things happening in my program, some of which are embedded in the resources I'm using, not to mention I feel like it's probably not good form to have them everywhere.

That being said, I'm wondering if there's a way to cause an event (likely just a dialog box saying that an error occurred), so that a user without a view of the output window would know something had gone wrong. It would be nice if I could also grab the error message itself, but that isn't necessary. I'm alright with the error still occurring so long as the program can keep going if the issue is corrected.

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if it is possible what form it would take, like something that monitors the output or listens for errors, but I'm open to all information about this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your code with a `try/except` block and name the `Exception` to print it in the dialog, for example:

```
try:

    # your code

except Exception as e:

    print(e) # change this to be in your dialog
```

This way you will not use `try/except` many times in different places and you will catch basically any `Exception`. The other way is to `raise` custom exceptions for each error and catch them with `except`.

If you still don't want to use `try/except` at all, maybe start a `thread` to keep checking for certain variables (through a `loop`) and whenever you want to *start an error event* you just set that variable to `True` and the `thread` will start the error dialog. For instance:

```
import time
import threading

test1 = False
test2 = False

def errorCheck():
    while True:
        if test1:
            # start error dialog for error1
        if test2:
            # start error dialog for error2
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=errorCheck)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    # start your app
```

However, I recommend using `try/except` instead.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to use try/except but it seems like that's the only option. I'm combining try/except and threading, as I had a bit of threading going on anyway, and it seems to be working to some extend for now. Thanks!